# How can I increase the value of one page compared to other pages?

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engine-indexing

I have the following structure in my website :

```
                                       example.com
                                            |
            -------------------------------------------------------------
          Cat-1                           Page-A                   Blog-Page
            |                               |                          |
      ----------------               ----------------           ----------------
      |              |               |              |           |              |
  Product-1       Product-2      Product-1       Product-4    Post1          Post2
```

Product pages are categorized between two types of pages: Category Pages(Cat-1) & Special Pages(Page-A)
In my business, the priority of my pages is in the following order:

- Special Pages(Page-A)
- Category Pages(Cat-1)
- Post Pages(Post-1 , Post-2 and ...)
- Product Pages(Product-1 , Product-2 and ...)
- Home Page(example.com)

My problem here is that Google has prioritized pages as follows (base on search result):

- Product Pages(Post-1 , Post-2 and ...)
- Category Pages(Cat-1)
- Special Pages(Page-A)
- Post Pages(Post-1 , Post-2 and ...)
- Home Page(example.com)

Sitemap details for each entities :

- Special Pages (changefreq : daily, priority : 0.9)
- Category Pages(changefreq : daily, priority : 0.9)
- Product Pages (changefreq : daily, priority : 0.7)
- Post Pages (changefreq : weekly, priority : 0.6)

**How can I get this valuable to Google?**

Comment: What do you mean by "How can I get this valuable to Google?"

Comment: @trebo. it means: `hi google bot. my important pages is 'Special Pages'. So if users search for the word xxx, they should refer to this page. because this 'Special Pages' very important(it's valuable). if the google bot not found the xxx word in 'Special Pages' then 'Product Pages' shows(it means priority).

Comment: Google ignores the change frequency and priority fields in XML site maps. You might as well just remove those fields from your site maps because they aren't used and just make your site maps larger and more unwieldy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, you should check internal links. The distribution of links between the pages of your site must be done properly. For example, in any site, the most important page is the home page. The number of links made for the home page should be more than other pages of the site.
I think it is better for all 3 next important pages,  Cat1, PageA and Blog page make links in site menu.

Comment: thanks. I will check and if it is resolved, I will accept the answer. I will be back soon.

Comment: Navigation is also important for google.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I would focus on making your internal links communicate the "Special Pages" to Google by having your Category, Product and Post pages link to your Special pages.

As mentioned by @mehdi, internal linking is one of the ways to draw attention to what's important in your site.  However, in your case, it appears Special Pages are more important than you home page, so try to link to your Special pages whenever it's appropriate.

Remember it's important that your links are relevant to the linked text.  In other words, you want to make sure that the text in your link communicates what the user should expect to find when they click on your link.  Rather than just a link to a "Special Product Name" try to create links to content that answers your reader's questions.

An example of good hyperlink text might be "Problems our special product solves" versus a link with the text "Special Product".  If the user clicks on "Problems our special product solves" then it should take them to a page about "Problems our special product solves".  These more specific links will help Google have more context to understand your structure.

Lastly, your blog is a great place to build these links.  When you're writing new content, or updating old content and discussing your *special product*, try to include relevant links to your *special pages* as part of your content. Don't just put a link that says, "For more information read...", but rather `

> "when you're trying to solve
> `<href>problem XX, consider using special product name</href>`  as part of your solution"

Make it part of your blog's discussion, rather than just being tagged on the end of the content.

Lastly, give it time.  It can take several months before Google gathers enough data from links, user interactions and other factors before Google prioritizes pages the way you want them to appear.